# Qual erro? strtok C

Tags: c, string

Fiz o seguinte código que recebe uma string de 3 números separados por espaço, depois delimita-os e aloca cada numero em uma posição do array, no final ele imprimi o array, o código funciona porém  somente sem a 7° e 8° linhas. Gostaria que alguém me dissesse qual o erro e ensinasse como fazer para funcionar mesmo recebendo outros valores antes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int i = 0;
    char str[4], array[3];
    scanf ("%[^\n]", str);
    char * pch;
    fflush(stdin);
    pch = strtok(str, " ");

    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        array[i] = *pch;
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c ", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faze a declaração do seu array para receber o numero, `char str[4], array[3];`, você define um espaço muito pequeno para armazenar 3 números separados por espaço.

Quando faz a entrada `1 2 3` é armazenado `['1',' ','2',' ']`, então o numero 3 fica de fora da sua string para a quebra;

Aumente o `str` para `str[6]` que já resolve seu problema.